# How to make 2 restful apps communicate periodically so that the focus comes back to the calling app each time

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I would need to know how to make two Spring restful apps communicate periodically (let's say every 5 seconds) so that the focus always comes back to calling app each time and the communication between the two apps continues until stopped by a call to a specific rest endpoint?

So, at the moment I have two independent spring boot restful apps both in the localhost but configured to have different ports. Thus, how can I make the first app, in which the method is called by a rest api to start the communication (and send entity data) with the other app (receiving and saving the entity data). And indeed essential is the continuance of the periodical communication until stopped by a spesific call to the rest end point in the first app.

---

Ok, I will try to elaborate a bit more. And let's keep it as simple as possible.
The other rest app is meant to be like a device or app which simulates a device producing sensor-data every 5 seconds and sends it to the other rest app which receives it and saves it to database. Model for the data is very simple:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DeviceData implements Serializable {

@JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @NotNull
    private integer sensorId;

    @Column(precision = 21, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal value;
 ...
}
```

This sensor data based on this model will be generated / simulated (for example by using random numbers and timestamp) in the app that runs, let say in the local port 8090. Then the data must be sent every 5 sec to the rest api in the other, receiving app (running in local port 8080) which obviously need to have also the same model for the data. In the receiving app we probably need something like the following to capture the generated data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/plugindata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<DeviceData> getDeviceData(@RequestBody DeviceData deviceData) {
    ... save to db ....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceData, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Also, from the receiving (also thus the controlling) app, some how, we need to turn on / off the device app which generates sensor-data. Obviously we need for that too rest api which locates in rest controllers of both the apps. In the device app something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/devices/{deviceid}/onOff/{onOffval}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> turnDeviceOnOff(@PathVariable String deviceid,
                                                   @PathVariable boolean onOffval) {
        if (onOffval == false) {
            this.isDeviceOn = false;
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
        try {
            this.isDeviceOn = true;
            return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
       }
    }
```

... and in the receiving (controlling) app we also need similar kind of rest method and endpoint to be called from the app in the front. So, in the front app we have a switch to switch on/off the generator-device - indeed mediated via the controlling app up to the device app, see?

I hope this clarifies even a bit more

Comment: The easiest way would be to have a cron job that does the call to one of the apps on behalf of the other.

Comment: this is a very unclear procedure. Couldn't you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution finally on my own. The solution is based on using RestTemplate in both of the applications and communication between apps thus takes place directly over the rest apis. And the cyclic data is generated with Timer:

...

```
 this.timer = new Timer();
 this.timer.schedule(new CreateDeviceData(deviceid), 0, 5000);

class CreateDeviceData extends TimerTask {

    public DeviceData device_data;
    private String deviceId;

    CreateDeviceData(String deviceid) {
       this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int sensor_id = (int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1;
        double sensor_value = (double) (Math.random() * (1000 - 1)) + 1;
        LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        DeviceData deviceData = new DeviceData(timestamp, sensor_id, sensor_value);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/plugindata";            
        DeviceData devicedata = restTemplate.postForObject(url, deviceData, DeviceData.class);

    }
    ...
```

Here the generated device data is posted back to the receiving (controlling) application where I have api to get the data and save it to db. Works nicely.